# Why is colspan and rowspan not formatting correctly in this table?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have pasted my code below as well as a picture of what I am trying to accomplish. "Header 2" should span 3 columns instead of 2 and "DataA1",B1,C1 should span 2 columns instead of 1. But when I specify that in my code it doesn't do anything. I am not sure what error I have run into.

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.title {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="4" class="title">A common header for three subheads</th>
    <th rowspan="2">Header 3</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Header 1</th>
    <th colspan="3">Header 2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Thing A</th>
    <td colspan="2">dataA1</td>
    <td>dataA2</td>
    <td>dataA3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Thing B</th>
    <td colspan="2">dataB1</td>
    <td>dataB2</td>
    <td>dataC3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Thing C</th>
    <td colspan="2">dataC1</td>
    <td>dataC2</td>
    <td>dataC3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a final row that actually contains five cells for the behaviour of `colspan="2"` to be visible.

Then add a width to `th` and `td` to maintain the correct styles, and you can hide the empty row to match your design.

```css
table, th, td  {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.title {
  padding: 10px;
}

th, td {
  width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<h1>Table</h1>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="4" class="title">A common header for three subheads</th>
    <th rowspan="2">Header 3</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Header 1</th>
    <th colspan="3">Header 2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Thing A</th>
    <td colspan="2">dataA1</td>
    <td>dataA2</td>
    <td>dataA3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Thing B</th>
    <td colspan="2">dataB1</td>
    <td>dataB2</td>
    <td>dataC3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Thing C</th>
    <td colspan="2">dataC1</td>
    <td>dataC2</td>
    <td>dataC3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="visibility: hidden;" aria-hidden="true">
    <th></th><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

"data A1" and the two cells below it *do*  span two columns, and "Header2 " *does*  span three columns, but there is no row where you would see this additional divison between column two and three. If you add a row with five cells you see what I mean (I only added that last row, I didn't change your code otherwise):

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.title {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Table</h1>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="4" class="title">A common header for three subheads</th>
    <th rowspan="2">Header 3</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Header 1</th>
    <th colspan="3">Header 2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Thing A</th>
    <td colspan="2">dataA1</td>
    <td>dataA2</td>
    <td>dataA3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Thing B</th>
    <td colspan="2">dataB1</td>
    <td>dataB2</td>
    <td>dataC3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Thing C</th>
    <td colspan="2">dataC1</td>
    <td>dataC2</td>
    <td>dataC3</td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
    <th>Thing D</th>
    <td>dataD1a</td>
    <td>dataD2</td>
    <td>dataD3</td>
    <td>dataC4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```